# Debugging an AUTOLOAD that calls a DynaLoader'd library

Tags: perl, debugging

Stepping through a vendor-provided library, a call is `AUTOLOAD`'ed, a coderef captured by a `UNIVERSAL::can()`, and that coderef called. I believe the call is to a routine from a compiled library via DynaLoader.

The trouble is, when it gets to this line `$result = &$coderef(@args)` the debugger doesn't step in to whatever the coderef is, it just takes me to the next line of the module itself. However, I am warned `Use of uninitialized value in string ne at (eval 1) line 1670`, which makes me think that coderef is more than just a call to an external library.

I've tried `s $coderef->(@args)` by hand and "stepped" in to it, and it's the same warning and no other interaction with the call.

Is there a way to prove that this is a wrapper, and maybe even force the debugger to see within it?

**EDIT** more code context (substantially trimmed routine from CQPerlExt.pm, the IBM ClearQuest Perl API):

```
sub AUTOLOAD {
    my @args = @_;
    (my $sub = $AUTOLOAD) =~ s/::/_/g;
    my $coderef = UNIVERSAL::can(__PACKAGE__."c", $sub)
        or Carp::croak "Undefined subroutine &$AUTOLOAD called";

    my $result = &$coderef(@args);
    return $result;
}
```

It works, the intended routine does what it's supposed to, but warns me when line 7 is executed. The debugger 's'teps through to line 8.

There is a CQPerlExtc package, which is a bootstrap for the external library.

In this case, @args contains a reference to the ClearQuest "entity" object, and the string 'modify' (both of which are appropriate to this call).

Comment: So you are saying that the code gets a reference to an AUTOLOAD generated method? Can you show a little more code? This sounds interesting.

Comment: The author of the XS/C code might be using the Perl API directly in such a way that causes this warning.  I'd guess that's because the method is getting a value passed in @args that it is not expecting.  What is contained in @args?

Comment: FYI, at this moment, the leading theory regarding these warnings is that they're coming from the ClearQuest perl hooks attached to the 'Modify' action, and not the primary script.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that is to simply write a test program in C that then simulates what you're trying to do in the Perl. I wish there was a better way to debug C code running through DynaLoader, but so far I haven't seen one. I also just cracked the pocket reference for the Perl debugger, and I don't see any mention of DynaLoader.

I'd just pull this into the debugger, copy the values being passed to the C function into a C program, and then run gdb on it.